# Where does attack helicopter's rockets land?

Tags: battlefield-3

Some people say it is the "I" sign, others say it is the "crosshair" and some say it is somewhere in the middle.

It would be good to clear this issue up once and for all. Please don't just write "I" or crosshair with no explanation. I am sure there are lots of guys out there with this question in their minds. So for the community to be sure, you need to provide a very solid proof or justification.

Comment: I am so tempted to just write "I" or "crosshair" xD

Comment: :))) That would be an incomplete answer.

Comment: It does depend on the distance to target, but the linked video is very good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suck as a helicoptor pilot, but Munchies is very good. He shows that the best way to line up the rockets is to use the top of the "I" beam.

Comment: I will check this out as soon as possible.

Comment: I downloaded and watched the video numerous times frame-by-frame and still I am not sure about the top of the "I" beam. Just go to 3:00-3:01 and watch it frame-by-frame and you will see that there is no way that the rockets go to the top of the "I". But in some other moments the rockets don't go to the crosshair neither. This is very confusing...

Comment: @Anar you do realize that the heli is not just staying at one place? It moves forward as well(not sure about altitude), so the top of the `I` would go lower and lower the faster you go(I mean the `I` at the moment of a missile impact)

Comment: @Novarg Of course I am taking that into account.

Comment: @Novarg That's why it is hard to pinpoint where the rockets land, hence the question.

Comment: yes, that is true.  So because movement makes the exact location of where the rockets land difficult to determine, if we take movement out of the picture we should be able to tell exactly how it works.  Try parking the heli on the top of a building and then fire the rockets.  That should tell you exactly where on the HUD the rockets land.

Comment: Also, note that the different choppers may use target differently.

Comment: When the helicopter is stationary, both the crosshair and the I-beam are on top of each other and the rockets go to the middle. So it is  not possible to tell to which one they are going.